# flutter blue reading characterstics error

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

Some one please solve this problem:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(read_characteristic_error, unknown reason, may occur if readCharacteristic was called before last read finished., null, null)

sample code:

```
# device connection
final device_connection = await r.device.connect();
    # find services
    List<BluetoothService> services = await r.device.discoverServices();
    # reads characterstics
    services.forEach((service) async {
      // Reads all characteristics
      var characteristics = service.characteristics;
      for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
        List<int> value = await c.read();
        print(value);
      }

      await c.write([0x12, 0x34]);
```

Comment: Can you please paste sample code and mention what output you're expecting.

Comment: can you share code

Comment: code was shared kindly see and tell me the solution with code thanks

Comment: you use {BluetoothCharacteristic c} out of scope...

Comment: how can i solve it?